# DynamoDB Type mismatch: cannot convert from CreateTableResult to Table

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In Eclipse Java EE IDE , I am trying to programmatically create a DynamoDB table. I have the method below, which is borrowed from several other sources. At `Table table = DYNAMODB.createTable(request)`, Eclipse is giving the exception: Type mismatch: cannot convert from CreateTableResult to Table.

```
public static final String S3_BUCKET_CHANNELS = "channels";
public static final String S3_BUCKET_EPISODES = "episodes";
public static final String SQS_QUEUE_NAME = "queue";
public static final String DYNAMODB_TABLE_CHANNELS = "channels";
public static final String DYNAMODB_TABLE_EPISODES = "episodes";

public static final String MACRO_PATH = "macros/";
public static final String FINISHED_PATH = "final/";

public static final AWSCredentialsProvider CREDENTIALS_PROVIDER =
            new ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider();

public static final Region REGION = Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2);

public static final AmazonS3Client S3 = new AmazonS3Client(CREDENTIALS_PROVIDER);
public static final AmazonSQSClient SQS = new AmazonSQSClient(CREDENTIALS_PROVIDER);
public static final AmazonDynamoDBClient DYNAMODB = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(CREDENTIALS_PROVIDER);
public static final DynamoDBMapper DYNAMODB_MAPPER = new DynamoDBMapper(DYNAMODB, CREDENTIALS_PROVIDER);

static {
    DYNAMODB.setRegion(REGION);
    SQS.setRegion(REGION);
}

public static void createChannelsTable() throws Exception {
            List<AttributeDefinition> attributeDefinitions = new ArrayList<AttributeDefinition>(1);
            attributeDefinitions.add(new AttributeDefinition().withAttributeName("url").withAttributeType(ScalarAttributeType.S));
            attributeDefinitions.add(new AttributeDefinition().withAttributeName("title").withAttributeType(ScalarAttributeType.S));

            List<KeySchemaElement> keyDefinitions = new ArrayList<KeySchemaElement>(2);
            keyDefinitions.add(new KeySchemaElement().withAttributeName("url").withKeyType(KeyType.HASH));

            ProvisionedThroughput provisionedThroughput = new ProvisionedThroughput(50l, 50l);

            GlobalSecondaryIndex globalSecondaryIndex =
                    new GlobalSecondaryIndex().withIndexName("channelIndex")
                                              .withProjection(new Projection().withProjectionType(ProjectionType.ALL))
                                              .withKeySchema(
                                                      new KeySchemaElement("title", KeyType.HASH),
                                                      new KeySchemaElement("url", KeyType.RANGE)
                                              )
                                              .withProvisionedThroughput(provisionedThroughput);

            CreateTableRequest request =
                    new CreateTableRequest().withTableName(DYNAMODB_TABLE_CHANNELS)
                                            .withKeySchema(keyDefinitions)
                                            .withAttributeDefinitions(attributeDefinitions)
                                            .withProvisionedThroughput(provisionedThroughput)
                                            .withGlobalSecondaryIndexes(globalSecondaryIndex);

            try {
                Table table = DYNAMODB.createTable(request);
                table.waitForActive();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Unable to create table: ");
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }

        }
```

Casting the Table does not work, and oddly enough, when I import this into Eclipse Neon there is no error. I'm using `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Table` from aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.10.42.jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `createTable` on `DYNAMODB`, which in your case is an instance of `AmazonDynamoDBClient`.

Rather, you need to call `createTable` on an instance of `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.DynamoDB`. More specifically, change your code like this:

```
public static final AmazonDynamoDBClient DYNAMODB_CLIENT = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(CREDENTIALS_PROVIDER);
public static final DynamoDB DYNAMODB = new DynamoDB(DYNAMODB_CLIENT);

...

Table table = DYNAMODB.createTable(request);
table.waitForActive();
```

See a complete example [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.Java.01.html).

Comment: Without a doubt, this is correct. Thank you for helping!